# Json syntax error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Tags: javascript, json

```
window.addEventListener('load, initialize());

'use strict'

console.log('Im working);

var c = [
    ["TEST!","TEST@"]
];

function initialize() {
    console.log(c[0].[1]);
}
```

I have tried for hours to make this code print out "TEST!", But the google console debugger, will no matter what I try, will say that the last set of square brackets is a unexpected Token. At this point, I just don't know what to do.

Comment: Error 1 : `ner('load', initialize);` Error 2 : `c[0][1]`

Comment: Eliminate that dot between brackets. `c[0][1]`

Answer (score 2):

bracket notation does not use dots

```js
var c = [ [1,2] ];
console.log(c[0][1]);
```

Another issue with your code is

```
window.addEventListener('load, initialize());
```

If initialize is returning a function it is correct. If it is not returning a function, than you are calling the method before the page load and assigning what it returns to the load event listener.